# На чём работают Minecraft Java сервера? Bukkit, и т.д на чём они работают, какой фреймворк, каково устройство Minecraft Java серверов на уровне хоста

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Через какие фреймворки работают Minecraft Java, Bukkit или Spigot и т.д. сервера? Как это работает на уровне хоста и сервера? Через что происходит управление RCON в Minecraft серверах? Хочу подробного ответа, или статей, литературу на эту тему, но именно не в целом про Java, а более узко, только по Minecraft.

Comment: Глупо конечно звучит, но minecraft сервера работают на minecraft сервере, который написал разработчик. Не секрет, что minecraft поддерживает систему моддинга и плагинов, чем и пользуются люди. Ваш вопрос можно свести к "как пишутся плагины и моды". Исходный код этих плагинов есть на github и любой желающий может ознакомится подробнее. Правда сейчас github слег, поэтому посмотреть описание не могу: https://github.com/Bukkit.

Answer (score 1):

- На чём работают Minecraft Java сервера? На Java.
- Фреймворк - Vanilla (закрытый исходный код), Bukkit или Spigot.
- Каково устройство Minecraft Java серверов на уровне хоста (jar библиотека)
- Как работают? Нормально )))

Скачиваешь java jre (нужен) и jdk (если захочешь ставить плагины).

Качаешь сервер с https://getbukkit.org/

Далее читаешь официальную документацию о том как поставить https://bukkit.fandom.com/wiki/Setting_up_a_server

Открываешь порты TCP/UDP 25565 и UDP 19132 на файрволле.

Запускаешь сервер, радуешься... )))

Дальнейшую инфу

- Ищи на официальной Wiki - https://bukkit.fandom.com/
- Или на российском ресурсе по ведёрку - http://rubukkit.org/

Comment: ps: За отдельное вознаграждение, пишу и устанавливаю плагины под заказ.